# Routing in Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

In Meteor I'm using Backbone in order to provide routing for the different pages in my app. I currently have a profile and an administration page. When I go to the profile page it shows up just as it should, however when I go to administration Meteor falls back to the main page.

As a side-note, if anyone has a better pattern or best-practice for pages in Meteor feel free to share as this is quite cumbersome.

I use the following template to decide what page to show:

```
<template name="root">
    {{> navbar}}
    {{#if pageIs "profile"}}
      {{> profile}}
      {{else}}{{#if pageIs "administration"}}
        {{> administration}}
      {{else}}
        {{> main_page}}
      {{/if}}
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

The pageIs method is as follows:

```
Template.root.pageIs = function(page){
    console.log(Session.get('page'));
    return page === Session.get('page');
}
```

And the following code in my Backbone router:

```
var ProtonRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "profile": "profile",
        "admin": "administration",
        "administration":"administration"
    },
    profile: function () {
        Session.set('page','profile');
    },
    administration: function (){
        Session.set('page', 'administraion');
    },
    mainPage: function(){
        Session.set('page',null);
    }
});
```

The log statement in the pageIs method will log undefined a couple of times and then log the correct page, even on administration, however Meteor doesn't seem to reload the selected page anyway and the template still hits the last else-statement.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Iron router is being deprecated in favor of Flow Router. There are [strong indications that Flow Router will be supported as part of core Meteor](https://forums.meteor.com/t/iron-router-becoming-incompatible-switch-to-flow-router-or-wait-for-mdg-router/) in the future.

> https://github.com/meteorhacks/flow-router

**OUTDATED**: The previously commonly used router was Iron Router:

> https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router

At its release, Iron Router combined the efforts of the authors of the two most widely used meteor routers ([meteor-router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router) and [mini-pages](https://github.com/cmather/meteor-mini-pages)), and was the de facto offcial router for Meteor prior to Flow Router.

Answer (score 9):

Lot of people use this route system:

https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router

It's really easy to use and made for Meteor.

Comment: Thanks! Gonna give that a try.

Comment: This is now outdated, and development has stopped. See accepted post for successor.

Answer (score 1):

In the early days of Meteor the recommendation was to use Backbone for routing.

The router Andrew pointed out in his post, has become the most popular choice: https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router

A more minimalistic solution is flow router: https://github.com/meteorhacks/flow-router

To make an informed decsion which one to use, you can [read about the differences](https://github.com/meteorhacks/flow-router#difference-with-iron-router) of both routers.